# FileNotFoundException in Scheduled query of BigQuery in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In BigQuery of GCP, i have a scheduled query that runs every 1 hour and the query has 15 columns and approximately 200k records will be results but sometimes once in a day or two, i get this issue. I have searched in BigQuery doc and googled, didn't get any idea about it.

```
8:33:50 PM  Summary: succeeded 0 jobs, failed 1 jobs.   
8:33:17 PM  Job scheduled_query_609c2fae-0000-2ffc-95fd-089e082bbc08 (table pnresultdaily) failed with error NOT_FOUND: Not found: Files /bigstore/data-external-gcs/15SffL_EhehW0Txv_bgXMDLEfiVZIei0iK9mQ_OLhROs.csv; JobID: 451294962789:scheduled_query_609c2fae-0000-2ffc-95fd-089e082bbc08
7:40:03 PM  Job scheduled_query_609c2fae-0000-2ffc-95fd-089e082bbc08 (table pnresultdaily) started. 
7:40:01 PM  Starting to process the query job with no parameters.   
7:40:00 PM  Dispatched run to data source with id 2294327365273823
```

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Maybe you should file a bug report with Google?

Comment: do you use external table?

Comment: No, we don't use external table